# Excel - Displaying a value in a cell dependent on another cell having text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, cells

I have an excel file with 2 sheets.  The first sheet is a user input sheet with cells that are properly formatted for us.  The second sheet pulls the raw data into table format so that we can inport into SQL (I know it sounds weird, but trust me, that's what we need).  I only want to display cell B1 if C1 is populated, so I use the following formula in cell B1:

```
=IF(C1="","",Sheet1!A24)
```

This works fine, but my cells have a formula in them because it's referencing my user input sheet.  Cell C1 has the formula:

```
=Sheet1!E23
```

Even though it still has a blank "value", the formula above does not see the cell as blank and doesn't do what I need.  Is there any solution for this?

Thank you kindly,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "blank 'value'", whether that means it is actually blank or just showing as "0".  But I plugged the provided information in Excel and it seems that your issue may be that C1 is showing as value "0", and so B1 is displayed?  If so, you could try making C1 similar to B1:

```
=IF(Sheet1!E23="","",Sheet1!E23)
```

So if there is no value in Sheet1!E23, it will show as blank in C1, which will mean B1 will not populate according to the B1 formula.

Comment: That definitely made sense.  Thank you.  It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but put me on the right track.  I'm using a different cell to check whether there is a value or not.  Works great.  Thanks so much for the help!